# Change parent state from child (where both are functional components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-functional-component

The layout for the following problem looks like this:

```
.
├── components
│   ├── ModalPolicy.js
│   ├── Footer
│       ├── index.js
├── pages
│   ├── index.js
```

I've tried to render the Modal on `Footer/index.js` but it didn't show up (as the one we have in `pages/index.js` does).

Therefore, I'd like to not only render my 'antd' Modal on `pages/index.js` but also hold the Modal state (opened vs closed) on `pages/index.js` while having it's "open" method being fired from a button in `Footer/index.js` since that's where our Footer-ish links already live.

The hindrance is that all components involved in this problem are functional components and every solution I've found on the internet addresses cases where the parent (or both) is a (are) class-component(s). The general gist of what I'd like to accomplish is as follows:

**components/Footer/index.js**

```js
// imports..

const Footer = (openModalHandler) => {
  return (
    <section id="footer">
      <Layout>
        <div className="content">
          <a href="#footer" onclick={openModalHandler}>
            Policy
          </a>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </section>
  )
}
```

**pages/index.js** (next.js)

```js
// imports..
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import ModalPolicy from '../components/ModalPolicy'

const Index = () => {
   const [openPolicy, setOpenPolicy] = React.useState(false)
   const closeModalPolicy = () => { /* Called by the Modal itself, don't bother with this */
      setOpenPolicy(false)     
   }
   const openModalHandler = () => { /* Called in Footer/index.js */
      setOpenPolicy(true)
   }

   return (
      <>
        <Some />
        <Other />
        <Stuff />
        <ModalPolicy open={openPolicy} onClose={closeModalPolicy} />
        <Footer openModalHandler={openModalHandler}
      </>
   )
}
```

**components/ModalPolicy.js**

```js
// imports..
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd'

const ModalPolicy = ({ t, open, onClose }) => {
   return (
      <Modal
        title="Política de uso y privacidad"
        visible={open}
        onCancel={onClose}
        footer={null}
        width="fit-content">
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: 
              `<h1>I'd really like to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML here</h1>
               <h2>It would make things a lot easier (assuming it won't look like crap on the browser)</h2>
              `
          }}
      </Modal>
  )
}
```

Notes: I'm not quite sure if I really have to render the Modal on pages/index.js for it to show up correctly. Actually, I'm pretty inexperienced with React (since I'm a backend dev) and browser-side javascript in general.

If there's an easier way to accomplish this, please, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Your pseudo code should work.. what issue are you having? Can you supply a reproducible example using a Stack Snippet? (if you have to, use a CodePen or CodeSandbox)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you forgot to destructure the properties out of the Footer component's props. Right now you are not passing the individual function through on the click handler but rather an object with the function.

aka change `const Footer = (openModalHandler)` to `const Footer = ({openModalHandler})`

```
const Footer = ({openModalHandler}) => {
----------------^----------------^ // curly brackets to desturcture
  return (
    <section id="footer">
      <Layout>
        <div className="content">
          <a href="#footer" onClick={openModalHandler}>
------------------------------^------ // capitalize the c (camelCase properties)
            Policy
          </a>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Without destructuring the param for your footer component is the `props` that react receives, which is an object with the key `openModalHandler`

[Play with it live if you'd like :)](https://codepen.io/jruddell/pen/LYVdgpe)

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the fast reply! You caught me in the middle of an edit, I'm actually doing `const Footer = (openModalHandler) => { /* ... */ }`.. with that said, could you investigate further? I'll edit the question to fix it.

Comment: @pietro-tavares your comment also isn't pulling out the key correctly, remember to add curly brackets to pluck keys from the `props` object. Also I edited to include another typo for your click handler.

Comment: Your suggestions + some other small fixes in the code got the job done. It works as intended now. Thanks!